# Python Binary Search Tree: Search function error

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, key, parent = None): 
        self.key = key
        self.parent = parent 
        self.left = None 
        self.right = None
        if parent != None:
            if key < parent.key:
                parent.left = self
            else:
                parent.right = self

    def search(self, key):
        if self == None:
            return (False, None)
        if self.key == key:
            return (True, self)
        elif self.key > key:
            return self.left.search(key)
        elif self.key < key:
            return self.right.search(key)
        else:
            return (False, self)
```

```
t1 = Node(25)
t2 = Node(12, t1)
t3 = Node(18, t2)
t4 = Node(40, t1)

print('-- Testing search -- ')
(b, found_node) = t1.search(18)
assert b and found_node.key == 18, 'test 8 failed'
(b, found_node) = t1.search(25)
assert b and found_node.key == 25, 'test 9 failed'
(b, found_node) = t1.search(26)
assert(not b), 'test 10 failed'
assert(found_node.key == 40), 'test 11 failed'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/practice/main.py", line 50, in <module>
    (b, found_node) = t1.search(26)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/practice/main.py", line 27, in search
    return self.right.search(key)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/practice/main.py", line 25, in search
    return self.left.search(key)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'
```

My search function is getting an error with the recursive calls to search(self.left, key) and search(self.right, key). It says search() takes 2 positional arguments, but is getting 3, and I am not understanding how this is happening?

Comment: Try `Node.search(self.left, key)` and `Node.search(self.right, key)`. Since you're invoking the `search` method of the `self` instance, the `self` instance gets passed implicitly as the first argument.

Comment: Make a [mcve] that constructs a few nodes and creates the error when calling Search.

Comment: You should be saying `self.left.search(key)`.  Remember that calling `self.search` supplies `self` as the automatic first parameter.

Comment: What if the parent already has a left or right key? The parent should be in charge of adding a new node to its (possibly empty) left or right child as appropriate, rather than the node trying to insert itself.

Comment: `self` will never be `None`, unless you unconventionally call `Node.search` directly rather than via an instance of `Node`. When `self.left` is `None`, `self.left.search(...)` is an `AttributeError`, not the same as `Node.search(None, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I really had a brain fart with this question.... Thank you to those commenting reminding me the function is being called with the self instance being passed implicitly, I forgot basics of objects i guess lol. This implementation passes the test cases. If there is a better way of implementing this, feel free to post, as I would love to see them...

```
def search(self, key):
    if self == None:
        return (False, self)
    if self.key == key:
        return (True, self)
    elif self.key > key:
        if self.left == None:
            return (False, self)
        else:
            return self.left.search(key)
    else:
        if self.right == None:
            return (False, self)
        else:
            return self.right.search(key)
```